# Regex to remove p tags within li tags and td tags

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this html content:

```
<p>This is a paragraph:</p>
<ul>
<li>
<p>point 1</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>point 2</p>
<ul>
<li>
<p>point 3</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>point 4</p>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<p>point 5</p>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
<p><strong>sub-head : </strong>This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading</p>
</li>
<li>
<p><strong>sub-head 2: </strong></p>
<p>This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove all the <p>&</p> tags between <li>&</li> irrespective of its position between <li>&</li>. similarly i need to remove p tags between td tags inside a table.

This is my controller code so far:

```
nogo={"<li>\n<p>" =>'<li>', "</p>\n</li>" => '</li>', "<td>\n<p>" => '<td>', "</p>\n</td>" => '</td>', 
  '<p> </p>' => '','<ul>' => "\n<ul>",'</ul>' => "</ul>\n", '</ol>' => "</ol>\n"   , 
  '<table>' => "\n<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='table table-curved'>", 
 '&lt;' => '<', '&gt;'=>'>','<br>' => '','<p></p>' => '', ' rel="nofollow"' => ''

c=params[:content]
       bundle_out=Sanitize.fragment(c,Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::BASIC,
       :elements=> Sanitize::Config::BASIC[:elements]+['table', 'tbody', 'tr', 'td', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3'],
       :attributes=>{'a' => ['href']}) )#.split(" ").join(" ")

      re = Regexp.new(nogo.keys.map { |x| Regexp.escape(x) }.join('|'))

      @bundle_out=bundle_out.gsub(re, nogo)
```

im passing the above html content to this code through params[:content] which ive assigned to a variable c.

Following is the o/p which is not as expected. Some close p tags and open p tags are still between li and close li tags

```
<p>This is a paragraph:</p>

<ul>
<li>point 1</li>
<li>point 2</p>
<ul>
<li>point 3</li>
<li>point 4</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>point 5</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li><strong>sub-head : </strong>This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading</li>
<li><strong>sub-head 2: </strong></p>
<p>This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading, This is a para followed by heading</li>
</ul>
```

My aim is simple i just want to remove all the p tags inside li and td tags, which im not able to do correctly. Any help is appreciated.

I would like to use regex to do this. and i know using regex is not the correct way to parse html content.

Comment: Use a parser, not HTML.

Comment: I suggest you use Nokogiri gem.

Comment: If you know it's not the correct way, why do it? I don't mean that as an offense, I'm asking for clarification - unless you can be very convincing that a parser is not the right solution, that may be the only answer you get

Comment: Have you read the famous regex harmless parsing post?

Comment: If you know that regex are NOT the recommended way to do this, then why ask? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/128421. Asking us how to do it then becomes a waste of effort, because no matter how much work we, or you, do, the regex will ultimately fail to do the job you want. That's not a good use of time or effort. Also, please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. They will help your ability to ask questions. Using correct grammar, and putting the effort into asking a question well pays off.

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend using regex because they're a dead-end unless the HTML is trivial and you create it. And, if you are the one creating it, then modifying it after generating it is the wrong way to go about generating content.

Use a parser. [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is the de-facto standard for Ruby, and, with some knowledge of CSS or XPath, you can quickly learn to search, or modify, HTML and XML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>foo</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          <p>bar</p>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('li p').each do |p_tag|
  p_tag.remove
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Running that results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>

      </li>
      <li>
        <span>

        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The tutorials on the Nokogiri site are your starting point. Stack Overflow is also a good resource as there are many different easily-searchable questions about all aspects of using the gem.